# can't convert html tag string to TCPDF html view

Tags: php, html, laravel, tcpdf

i have php laravel project function to create pdf view. right now im using TCPDF helper for laravel [elibyy/tcpdf-laravel](https://github.com/elibyy/tcpdf-laravel)

my code is similar like this in laravel controller

```
function createPDF()
{
  $html_tag_string = "<p>some paragraf <b>Test for example</b></p>";

  $view = \View::make('myPDFview', compact('html_tag_string ''));
  $html_content = $view->render();

  PDF::SetTitle("List of users");
  PDF::AddPage();
  PDF::writeHTML($html_content, true, false, true, false, '');

  return PDF::Output('myPDF'. date('Ymdhis') .'.pdf');
}
```

then i print or echo **$html_tag_string** variables on the **myPDFview**. im using **htmlentities()** function to convert string to html entities and decode using **html_entity_decode()** function, in normal load on web browser using echo it works, but when im pass to **myPDFview** it still showing raw html tag.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question (it's allowed and encouraged) but please respect Stack Overflow's Q&A format and don't add the answer inside the question.